# What is an Ado.net equivalent of this Ado sample?

Tags: ado.net, ado, vb6-migration

AFAIK ado.net datareaders and datasets don't seem to support joins in sql statements.

Is it possible to retrieve the ado.net equivalent of this ado recordset using just the information presented in this ado/vb code :
I am asking the question this way as I am trying to largely automate the conversion 
of ado to ado.net

```
    Dim myconn As New ADODB.Connection    
myconn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.3.51;Data Source=c:\TestDB1.mdb;Jet OLEDB:System Database=c:\TestDB1.mdw;User ID=TestDB;Password=123456;"    
myconn.Open()    
Dim myrec As New ADODB.Recordset    
Dim str1 As String = "select TableA.field0, tableB.field0 from TableA inner join TableB on TableA.field1 = TableB.field1 where tableA.field3 > 0 order by tableA.field4" 
 myrec.Open(str1, myconn)
```

Comment: Where did you hear that ADO.NET doesn't support joins ?
ADO.NET doesn't care what's in your SQL queries, it'll happily give you a DataReader or fill a DataSet for any queries the database/database driver can handle.

Comment: when I used  sql containing joins it threw a runtime exception 'join not supported' and when I looked it up i read that eg the fill method of the dataadaptor only worked on one table at a time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course ADO.NET supports joins!

See [ADO.NET: Retrieve Data using OLE DB quickstart](http://quickstarts.asp.net/QuickStartv20/howto/doc/adoplus/adodtreader.aspx) tutorial.

Comment: i looked but there aren't any examples with joins

Comment: Joins in the select statement, I mean

Comment: Dan, I'm an idiot. I got 'join not supported messages' and it was because of errors in my select syntax while I assumed that it meant joins not possible

Comment: Hey, no worries, we've all done similar things, believe me :)